Computation of Distance Matrix in SpatialRF
In a package SpatialRF, a distance matrix is required for fitting spatial random forest model. However, package does not provide function to compute it. One statement about the nature of distance matrix is given, that is, distance matrix requires the matrix of distances between the cases in data. In examples given in the package, they have used a pre-computed distance matrix. By applying Euclidean distance function dist() on the example data file, we get a matrix of same size, but with entirely different entries. If would be great if someone have used this pacakge and guide about computing distance matrix for spatial random forest model of this package.
